# newbie in snort

Tags: command-line, snort

I want to download SnortRules from command line but when I put it with this format:
I'm with Win Xp

In Opensuse I have apache,php and the curl extension but in Xp I have nothing. I don't have access to internet In Opensuse I just have access via WinXp

```
  http://www.snort.org/sub-rules/<filename>/<oinkcode here>
```

it tells me:

```
'http:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

what is the problem?

I entered this one:

```
http://www.snort.org/sub-rules/snortrules-snapshot-2900.tar.gz/59882...(myoinkcode here)
```

Comment: What is *it*?  Are you just typing the URL alone on the command line, or are you giving it as an argument to some command?  Which OS?

Comment: it will tell I need to use these tools:wget or curl yes I typed URL it is winxp but I have remote Opensuse that I have application In there that is for easy using of Snort

Comment: So, if you have a command prompt, and your prompt says something like `C:> `, do you then type in `curl http://www.snort.org/...`?  Not sure how primitive WinXP's command line is, but have you tried putting it in quotes?  e.g. `curl "http://www.snort.org/..."`?

Comment: please tell me that I must download the curl extension here? is it possible?

Comment: It sounds as if you don't even have curl installed.  You can get it for WinXP here: http://www.gknw.net/mirror/curl/win32/curl-7.21.7-ssl-sspi-zlib-static-bin-w32.zip

Comment: maybe I must install wamp server here it has curl extension by it's own cause I tried yours nothing changed

Comment: Then without seeing *exactly* what you're typing, there's not much I can do to help.  After installing the software that I referenced, you should have been left with a `curl.exe` which you could then execute.  The error you're getting is from the Window's command interpreter.

Comment: Now I am in OpenSuse I'm in internet by remote I'm trying shell,but not worked well! I found that it is absolutely from the installation ,but you helped,poblem is going to solved cause I wasn't here as adminstrator they will install curl.exe for me! thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the `curl` binary hasn't actually been installed.  You can get a copy for WinXP [here](http://www.gknw.net/mirror/curl/win32/curl-7.21.7-ssl-sspi-zlib-static-bin-w32.zip).  Once you have it installed (say in `C:\Programs\Curl` with the executable at `C:\Programs\Curl\curl.exe`), you can run:

```
C:> C:\Programs\Curl\curl.exe "http://www.snort.org/sub-rules/..."
```

And that will grab the data from the URL given and print it to your screen.  Run `curl.exe --help` for further instructions or look for help at the [cURL website](http://curl.haxx.se/).

Best of luck!

**EDIT:**

If you're use SuSE, then just install curl (it may already be installed), and at the command prompt type:

```
$ curl http://www.snort.org/...
```

And type this for help:

```
$ man curl       ...or...
$ curl --help
```